# Binding to viewmodel when in listbox itemssource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, scope

I have a listbox bound to an itemscollection. while in the list box I want to be able to access a property of my viewmodel.

VarA and VarB are properties of itemscollectionB and these are printed fine
VarC is a property in my viewmodel that I want to display alongside the other information

The message I am given is "Cannot resolve property VarC in data context of type 'Item' which I understand to be trying to access Item.VarC but I just want to access my public property VarC declared in my viewmodel

basically I need to print horizontally three things
itemscollectionB[i].VarA itemscollectionB[i].VarB, VarC

How can I do this

```
<ListBox Background="white" x:Name="Name"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsCollectionA}" 
         Margin="0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel >
                <ListBox BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsCollectionB}" 
                        FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="9" 
                        FontWeight="Bold">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial"  
                                    Text="{Binding Path=VarA}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial"  
                                    Text="{Binding Path=VarB}" Margin="5,0" />
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial"  
                                    Text="{Binding Path=VarC}" Margin="0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Ahh @Viv, you could have put that into an answer and saved me the trouble. :) I think you missed the `DataContext.` part though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general way to achieve this is to have a proper view model that contains *all* of the properties required by the relevant view. Now, assuming that you have set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of the relevant view model using one method or another, you should have `ItemsCollectionA` and `VarC` properties in this same view model.

If this is so, then we can simply use a `RelativeSource Binding` to access the view model from the `ItemTemplate`. Assuming your view is called `YourView`:

```
{Binding DataContext.VarC, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourView}}}
```

Looking at this, we can see that the `RelativeSource Binding` will look for a parent of type `YourView` and then it will look for a property named `VarC` in the object that is set as its `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.VarC,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Margin="0,0" />
```

Comment: -1 Sorry but check the previous replies and stop adding duplicates especially when there is no explanation of why your answer is any different from specifying `Window` as an explicit type.